# status : 200 statusText : OK readyState : 4

Tags: ajax

I have this url call using webservices is working fine but this same using in webmethod then not call to .cs SearchData webmethod.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",           
        url: "TestAjax.aspx/SearchData",
        data: '{ "ProductID" : "' + ProductID + '","ReferanceNO" : "' + ReferanceNO + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(' status : ' + data.status + ' statusText : ' + data.statusText + ' readyState : ' + data.readyState);
        }
});
```

it returns me

> status : 200 statusText : OK readyState : 4

Comment: i am using jquery-1.7.11.min.js JS. When call using webservices is working fine but this same using in webmethod then not call to .cs SearchData webmethod.

Comment: Add this in web.config

Comment: <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in web.config system.web section.

```html
<httpModules> <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/> </httpModules>
```